# Cassandra Web Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, kibana, graphite, grafana

I need to have a web dashboard with Cassandra to show data inside tables, keyspaces etc.
It should be similar to Kibana with Elasticsearch; actually I have tried Grafana with Cassandra but it ended up with only metrics.

How can I integrate Kibana (or Grafana, or other tools) with Cassandra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana and/or Grafana do not support Cassandra as a data source. You can use some other tools, but they do not look like Kibana/Grafana.
E.g. you can peek in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914413/any-suggestion-for-cassandra-database-gui)